# Cannot Create New Rails Project: `require': cannot load such file -- /config/boot (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a new Rails project,

```
Jakes-Air:code JakeWengroff$ rails new MyNewProject -T
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
script/rails:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/JakeWengroff/config/boot (LoadError)
from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

Checking the Ruby version, `ruby -v`, I get

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

When I want to check the version of Rails, `rails -v`, I get the same error as when I want to initiate a new Rails proejct:

```
script/rails:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/JakeWengroff/config/boot (LoadError)
from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

So, I reinstalled Rails, `gem install rails -v 4.2.0`:

```
Successfully installed rails-4.2.0
Parsing documentation for rails-4.2.0
Done installing documentation for rails after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I also did `bundle install` and `bundle check` and everything was fine.  But the error persisted.

After reviewing some other, similar questions here, I thought it had to do with gemsets. From the RVM [website](https://rvm.io/gemsets/creating), I decided to try `rvm gemset create rails420`, which gave me

```
ruby-2.1.2 - #gemset created /Users/JakeWengroff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails420
ruby-2.1.2 - #generating rails420 wrappers..............
```

But then trying `rails -v` and `rails new MyNewProject -T` still threw the original error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using `rvm`?

Comment: run `gem env` to your terminal & check the outputs. I believe your ruby installation has a problem. Check the command output. It will lead you to find the error.

Comment: @Emu What should I be looking at when I run `gem env`?  I think my Shell Path may have some issues:  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/JakeWengroff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin
     - /Users/JakeWengroff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin
     - /Users/JakeWengroff/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin
     - /Users/JakeWengroff/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/git/bin
     - /opt/sm/bin
     - /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin
     - /opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin

Comment: @Jake Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @Reinier Unfortunately, I have not.

Comment: @Jake, I have installed a new version of ruby with RVM and then installed rails on top of that. This solved the issue for me, but I am not sure if this is the right way..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, for me it turned out to be a problem with ruby. I have installed a different version of Ruby with RVM and installed the rails gem with this other version of Ruby.

```
rvm install 2.2.2

gem install rails
```

I would not recommend this solution as a sustainable one, but I couldn't solve this in a different way and at least it will get you going again.